# How to save blob url image in folder using express?

Tags: node.js, file, blob, react-admin

Hi I have this input in a request

```
{
  "title": "Places Search Box",
  "tags": "sd",
  "pictures": {
    "rawFile": {
      "path": "Screenshot 2020-03-05 at 12.05.55 PM.png"
    },
    "banner": "blob:http://localhost:3001/3b3dead6-bee0-4a9c-a0b3-28a560ee1558"
  }
}
```

how will I save this blob URL ***blob:http://localhost:3001/3b3dead6-bee0-4a9c-a0b3-28a560ee1558***  image in a folder using node.js.

when i am trying to save like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const myUrl = res.pictures.banner;


fs.writeFile("/myFolder/myFile", myUrl, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

then it'[image]s looking like this

Answer (score -2):

```
const fs = require('fs');

const res = {
  "title": "Places Search Box",
  "tags": "sd",
  "pictures": {
    "rawFile": {
      "path": "Screenshot 2020-03-05 at 12.05.55 PM.png"
    },
    "banner": "blob:http://localhost:3001/3b3dead6-bee0-4a9c-a0b3-28a560ee1558"
  }
}

const myUrl = res.pictures.banner;


fs.writeFile("/myFolder/myFile", myUrl, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

This is pretty straight forward, if you didn't understand just ask what you have missed.

Comment: its saving but image is not opening in image this blob:http://localhost:3001/fe9d7498-5358-4225-983f-cf5540c0a9a9 comes

Comment: I thought that was your aim, what is the purpose of saving the URL then why do you need it for?

Comment: i want to save this image not url